# Fire mouse listener of a previously selected node of a JTree

Tags: java, swing, jtree, jinternalframe

The application I'm working on uses a tree whose child nodes open JInternalFrames. Clicking on the same node after closing the corresponding Internal Frame doesn't launch a new instance.

Clicking another node(which also opens the corresponding frame) and clicking back works, though.

Code to open the Internal Frames.

```
public class MAdapter extends MouseAdapter{
    public void onClick(MouseEvent e){
        if(e.getSource()==jTree1){              
            DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) jTree1.getLastSelectedPathComponent();

            if(node == null)return;

            //Object nodeInfo = node.getUserObject();
            String child = node.getUserObject().toString();
            System.out.println("Child: "+child);

            //Object nodeParent =  node.getParent();
            String parent = node.getParent().toString();
            System.out.println("Parent: "+parent);              




            if(parent.equalsIgnoreCase("Client")){
                if(child.equalsIgnoreCase("Create")){
                    UIClient client = new UIClient();                       
                    openInternalFrame("Client Create",client);

                }else if(child.equalsIgnoreCase("Display")){
                    ClientView view = new ClientView();
                    openInternalFrame("Client View",view);
                }else if(child.equalsIgnoreCase("Change")){
                    EditClient edit = new EditClient();
                    openInternalFrame("Edit Client",edit);
                }
            }else if(parent.equalsIgnoreCase("Requirement")){
                if(child.equalsIgnoreCase("Create")){
                    openInternalFrame("Create Requirement",new Requirement());
                }else if(child.equalsIgnoreCase("Display")){
                    ViewRequirement view =  new ViewRequirement(null);
                    openInternalFrame("View Requirement",view);
                }else if(child.equalsIgnoreCase("Change")){
                    openInternalFrame("Edit Requirement",new EditRequirement());
                }
            }               
        }
    }
}
```

openInternalFrame method

```
 private void openInternalFrame(String name,Component com){

    JInternalFrame iframe = new JInternalFrame(name);
    iframe.addInternalFrameListener(this);
    iframe.setVisible(true);
    iframe.setMaximizable(true);
    iframe.setIconifiable(true);
    iframe.setClosable(true);
    iframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JInternalFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    iframe.setIconifiable(true);
    iframe.setLocation(300, 400);
    iframe.add(com);        
    iframe.requestFocus();
    iframe.moveToFront();



    JFrame topFrame = (JFrame) SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(thisFrame);
    topFrame.getContentPane().add(iframe);

    //topFrame.getContentPane().paint(getGraphics());
}
```

The example below works as I intend it to. It does not have the problem. The difference here is that I use a JFrame instead of a JInternalFrame. I'm guessing there's an error in one of the classes that are used to create the internal frame. Doesn't matter since I'm not working on it anymore. The mods should delete this question:

```
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel;

public class Example {

    static JTree tree;
    static JFrame mainWindow;
    static JScrollPane pane;

    public static void createTree(JScrollPane pane){
        DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Root");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode parent;
        DefaultMutableTreeNode child;
        parent = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Parent1");
        root.add(parent);
        child = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Child1");
        parent.add(child);
        child = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Child2");
        parent.add(child);
        parent = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Parent2");
        root.add(parent);
        child = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Child1");
        parent.add(child);
        child = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Child2");
        parent.add(child);

        tree = new JTree(new DefaultTreeModel(root));
        tree.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent evt){
                DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) tree.getLastSelectedPathComponent();

                if(node == null) return;
                else{
                    String child = node.getUserObject().toString();
                    String parent = node.getParent().toString();
                    System.out.println(parent);
                    System.out.println(child);

                    createSecondFrame(parent,child);
                }
            }
        });
        pane.setViewportView(tree);
    }

    public static void createSecondFrame(String parent, String child){
        JFrame secondary = new JFrame(parent+", "+child);
        secondary.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        secondary.setVisible(true);     
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        mainWindow = new JFrame("Example");
        pane = new JScrollPane();
        createTree(pane);
        mainWindow.setContentPane(pane);
        mainWindow.setSize(200,300);
        mainWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainWindow.setVisible(true);
    }

 }
```

Comment: Do you have any Exceptions?

Comment: Are you sure that the problem lies within the code posted? First try to simplify and isolate your problem -- is the JTree not responding to re-selection (my bet)? Something else? Then if still stuck, post a [mcve], a minimal program that compiles and runs, and demonstrates your problem for us.

Comment: I'd say it's the JTree since clicking on some other node and back works. Just clicking the same node doesn't. I've been wondering if JTree is even the right choice. No example I've seen has a need for the user to click the same node again. Even the println function doesn't work. There are no exceptions.

Comment: And I'd say that it's not JTree but rather the listener that you're using. No [mcve] though so ...

Comment: The onClick listener? It didn't work with a tree selection listener eithe. I'll post an example soon.